# How to issue multithreaded/non-blocking readdir in FUSE

Tags: filesystems, nonblocking, fuse

Right now, the `readdir()` in FUSE is a blocking method, which means that at anytime there is only one readdir() operation can be invoked. My file system may need support heavy simultaneously directory operations. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the multi threading mode when you mount your fuse filesystem. It's enable by default now.

You have to be double sure that your fuse fs implementation is thread safe before enabling multi threading.